# How to find out who killed a yarn application

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I'm looking for a way to find out the user who killed a YARN app. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in the newest version of Hadoop 2.9 and above. More detail will be shown related to the user who killed the application.
Check the following jira for more info 
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/YARN-5053